# Даёт/придаёт дополнительны(е/х) сил(ы)

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Очень режет слух, когда говорят *придаёт дополнительные силы.* По-моему, правильно говорить *даёт дополнительн**ые** сил**ы***, но ***при***даёт дополнительн**ых** сил. Причём с *даёт* ещё можно сказать в родительном падеже, а с *придаёт* в именительном, мне кажется, нельзя. Я прав?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я в основном по ответы Граммы от Бэла Вартанова.
Варианты "дополнительных"/"дополнительные" одинаково возможны и на мой вкус здесь очень близки по смыслу.

Здесь нет противоречия, плеоназма тоже нет. Ну плеоназм - вообще надумано, с чего бы глагол придать тут трактовать как ("дать еще", а не просто "дать"? - см. значения у Кунецова http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x).

А вот насчет падежа и двух значений - это интересно.
Ну да, в классическом понимании родительный против винительного есть такое, что первый отвечает за часть, чего-то добавленного, а второй просто констатирует (долить воды - долить воду, принести угля - принести уголь, достать чернил - достать чернила; последний пример, кстати, уже на грани синонимичности). Но у нас-то это не проходит.

В таком контексте альтернатива в понимании как "дать нечто новое" против "дать еще" у слова "дополнительные" просто отсутствует. Силы эти неизмеряемая, физически не фиксируемая величина, поэтому совершенно не важно, были ли какие-то силы (до того как "придали") или дополнительные это нечто совершенно самостоятельное.

*Эта специя придала блюду дополнительный вкус - Эта специя придала блюду дополнительного вкуса.* Ну есть у кого-то разумное объяснение, чем первое отличается от второго?
То же самое и с "дополнительными силами". Значения синонимичны, а грамматика позволяет использовать любой вариант.  Я бы, коли писать "навскидку", написал скорее именно "дополнительные силы". Но это чисто потому, что я мыслю конкретными категориями - и "силы" для меня имеет некоторое физическое воплощение. А в остальном спорить тут не о чем.

Comment: "Эта специя придала блюду дополнительного вкуса".  Звучит как фальшивая нота. Нет, грамотные люди так не говорят.

Comment: Ну изините, насчет нот - это не ко мне. За вкус можем поговорить, а петь не обучен. Претензии - к медведю, что мне ухо отдавил. Кстати, грамотные люди обычно не хамят на пустом месте. Если вы так не говорите, это еще не значит, что Вы грамотный.

Comment: Не мешайте работать людям своими минусовками, и меня не будет интересовать ваш музыкальный слух. Кстати, советую Вам перечитать то, что Вы говорите своим коллегам, постоянным участникам форума, из Ваших высказываний можно цитатник составить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! *С чего бы глагол придать тут трактовать как "дать еще", а не просто "дать"?* Действительно, 2-е значение тут как раз подходит.

Comment: Артем, приставка "при" уже указывает на прибавление, добавление.

Answer (score 2):

Толковый словарь Ушакова

> ПРИДАТЬ это:

Толкование
ПРИДАТЬ
ПРИДАТЬ
ПРИДА́ТЬ, придам, придашь, придаст, придадим, придадите, придадут, повел. придай, прош. вр. придал, придала, придало; придавший, совер. (к придавать).

1. кого-что. Дать сверх чего-нибудь, в дополнение к чему-нибудь, прибавить. К прежним деньгам придал еще триста рублей. Придать отряду артиллерию.
2. чего кому-чему. Прибавить, усилить, сделать более ощутительным что-нибудь (какое-нибудь качество, свойство) в ком-чем-нибудь. «Быть может качеств ваших тьму, любуясь им, вы придали ему?» Грибоедов. Любовь придала ему бодрости и силы. Присутствие товарища придало ему храбрости. Придать устойчивости. Придать больше яркости наряду. Придать вкусу чему-нибудь.
3. что кому-чему. Сообщить, усвоить чему-нибудь что-нибудь (какое-нибудь качество, свойство, состояние). Придать острый вкус блюду. Придать законную силу документу. Придать известию характер достоверности. Придать устойчивость. Придать прочность.
4. что кому-чему. Облечь в ту или иную форму, сообщить тот или иной вид, ту или иную внешность. Придать серьезное выражение своему лицу. Придать красивую внешность книге.
5. что кому-чему. Воспринимая что-нибудь, вложить тот или иной смысл, отнестись с тем или иным пониманием. Придать серьезное значение чьим-нибудь словам.

Оба варианта правильны. Выбирайте тот оттенок, который Вам нравится.

Comment: И что?*********

Answer (score 1):

В ответ внесены изменения:

Мне кажется, что правильным (**при наличии определения**) является сочетание "придать **дополнительные** силы".

Скорее всего, **схема такая**: имеется начальный запас сил; если они увеличиваются на какую-то величину, то это можно выразить **двумя способами**: (1) **придать сил** (**Р.п.,** партитивное/количественное значение, от partis - **часть**) - (2) **придать дополнительные силы** (**В.п**., здесь значение **частичного увеличения** передает прилагательное).

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

Дополнительные силы мотору придает механический компрессор.

Беглянка обладала недюжинной энергией, а опасность придала ей дополнительные силы ― она летела как птица.

Comment: Спасибо! "Получали дополнительные силы" — это не то, тут и не скажешь иначе. *Выражение "придать дополнительных сил" можно понять как "сначала дать дополнительные силы, а потом еще добавить дополнительных сил".* Не согласен. Сначала дать не дополнительные силы, а вообще силы тогда. Там было о лыжной гонке. Силы так или иначе уже есть, много или не очень. Ничего и давать не надо. И речь идёт о том, что какой-то фактор *придаёт дополнительных сил вдобавок к уже имеющимся, причём неопределённое количество.*

Comment: Может быть, Вы правы в своих рассуждениях о смысле выражений, но тут дело в грамматической форме, а с точки зрения грамматики, как мне кажется,  читается именно так. Придать силы, придать сил - вот здесь (без определения) обе формы воспринимаются нормально.  А вообще говоря, в Интернете употребляются оба выражения, здесь желательно определить частотность и качество текстов.

Answer (score 1):

ПРИДАТЬ - 1. **(Дать в дополнение, прибавить) что.**  Придать отряду артиллерию. Моим речам придай  очарованье. 2. **(увеличить, усилить какое-либо качество) чего.** Придать храбрости; Ольга Павловна едва не упала в обморок, но страх придал ей сил.

**Розенталь Д. Э. Управление в русском языке: Словарь-справочник. Для работников печати. — М.: Книга, 1981. — 207 с.**

Обратите внимание:  в словаре Кузнецова представлено только второе значение, с родительным падежом. Видимо, он объединяет эти два значения.

Хотя в Национальным корпусе русского языка можно встретить оба употребления.

Идея стоит того, потому что какие бы перспективы у детей ни были, эта возможность придает **им сил и** позволяет почувствовать себя социально адаптированными, — добавила Егорова. **[Павел Панов. ЕГЭ разрешили сдавать на больничной койке и дома // Известия, 2014.05.21]**

Бело-зеленая толпа болельщиков всегда придает команде **дополнительных сил. [Тимур Ганеев. Сонни Уимс: «Я лучший американец, играющий в Европе» // Известия, 2014.01.09] [омонимия не снята]**

Или можно отнестись к нему как к чуду, которое освобождает **и придает силы** для новых свершений. [Захар РАДОВ. Джоан Роулинг: Такого успеха, как с "Гарри Поттером", у меня больше не будет // **Комсомольская правда, 2013.11.12]**

**Это придает силы»** - Я сейчас получаю очень много трогательных телеграмм, писем из России. [Александр ГАМОВ. Евгений Евтушенко: «Мне не рано думать о потере жизни. А просто невозможно! Очень много дел» // Комсомольская правда, 2013.09.27] [омонимия не снята] ←…→
Это очень приятно. **Это придает силы.** И спасибо! [**Александр ГАМОВ. Евгений Евтушенко: «Мне не рано думать о потере жизни. А просто невозможно! Очень много дел» // Комсомольская правда, 2013.09.27**

Из параллельных персонажей — коррумпированный полицейский и африканский дипломат, оба — тоже в костюмах, африканский дипломат, понятно, выделяется на общем фоне, да и вообще, выступая в амплуа трогательного жулика на выезде, п**ридает фильму дополнительный шарм. [Марина Латышева. В прокате «Беспредел» Такеши Китано // РБК Дейли, 2013.04.23]**

**Хотя в последним примере, судя по рекомендации Розенталя должен быть родительный падеж, а здесь винительный.**

Comment: Я так и не понял, Вы согласны со мной?

Comment: Артем,обратите внимание на словарное значение: придавать (Дать в дополнение, прибавить) что. В вашем примере именно это значение.

Comment: Так и я абсолютно так же это понимаю! Поэтому для меня естественно с родительным падежом говорить. Придать вид, что-то ещё чему-то — это уже другой случай, мы не о нём.

Comment: Артем, но там не родительный падеж.

Comment: А-а, а я воспринял как родительный падеж ед. числа! Хм...

Comment: Артем, проблема в том, что данная рекомендация справочника Розенталя и словарей, как видно из примеров, на практике не соблюдается. Более того, в словаре Кузнецова приведено только второе значение с родительным падежом.

Comment: Конечно, можно было бы обратиться на Грамоту.ру. Но  вероятность получить от них ответа  - мала.

Comment: *А-а, а я воспринял как родительный падеж ед. числа! Хм* - ***а какой же еще?!*** Артем, ну вы хоть вчитывайтесь в то, чему поддакиваете. У Розенталя - родительный единственного, в вашем примере вариант: либо родительный, либо винительный, но оба множественного. То, что объект может быть единственного или множественного числа решительно никакой роли не играет.

Comment: И еще. Я Вам открою страшную тайну. Я хорошо знаю кухню "Грамоты", и догадываюсь, что происходит на "Грамме". В первом случае наверняка, а во втором - предположительно ответы пекут девочки-практикантки, уровень понимания которых постоянен, а желание его совершенствовать прямо зависит от финансирования, которое и раньше было не очень-то богатым. Поэтому ответ "Грамоты" или "Граммы" никак нельзя признать чем-то даже отдаленно сопоставимым с уровнем Розенталя (которого, кстати, тоже сильно дерозенталили после смерти). Подумайте над этим.

Comment: На Грамме отвечают кандидаты наук, в отличии от вас! Преподаватели с большим опытом. Вы бы посмотрели, что написано у Розенталя. Придать: дать в дополнение, прибавить.

Comment: Серж, В отличие от Вас, я говорю, то что знаю. И хватит уже переходить на личности. Я слишком хорошо знаю систему работы службы ответов и работу сайтов вообще. И научитесь уже писать в отличие через Е. Из раза в раз позоритесь. Насчет Розенталя. Вы сначала объясните, с чего бы я это должен смотреть Розенталя, а не Вы Салтыкова-Щедрина, например.

Comment: Прежде чем делать мне замечания, посмотрите лучше на свои ошибки, в ваших текстах бывает их уйма. Не знаете, что говорите. Я прекрасно знаю, кто работает на Грамме. И раз вы не верите Розенталю.... что же... тут уже ничего не скажешь.

Comment: *И раз вы не верите Розенталю.... что же... тут уже ничего не скажешь.* - и не раз и не два. Я верю Розенталю. Но Вы - не Розенталь. Увы. ==== Серж, я давно перестал делать ***Вам*** замечания, успокойтесь. Это бесполезно, я просто констатирую ваши очевидные ошибки, которые вы видите только у других. А вот, прежде чем отвечать мне в духе "сам дурак", вам не мешает немножко посмотреть на себя критически. Всё, дальнейшую распальцовку - переносите в чат.

Answer (score 1):

Задала вопрос Грамме.ру. Вот что они ответили.

### Ответ ГРАММЫ.РУ.

Оборот "придать дополнительных сил/дополнительные силы" небезупречен со стилистической точки зрения, так как глагол "придать" уже указывает на дополнение чего-либо чем-либо. Иными словами, это типичный плеоназм, характерный для разговорной речи.
Значение слова "дополнительный" может быть понято неоднозначно: "дополнительный - являющийся дополнением к чему-либо". "Дополнение" может осознаваться и как восполнение чего-либо недостающим (т. е. чем-то новым), и как восполнение в количестве чего-то уже существующего. Таким образом, слово "дополнительный" отсылает к двум значениям глагола "придать", порождая колебание в выборе падежной формы существительного.

Comment: Спасибо, Бэла!)

Comment: Заумь они ответили. Как всегда, впрочем. Ну замените "дополнительные" на "новые". Что все проблемы исчезнут? Ничуть не бывало. Такое впечатление, что они отвечают, даже не удосужившись вдуматься в смысл.

Answer (score 0):

> Я прав?

Вряд ли. Проще всего зайти в Нацкорпус и посмотреть.
А почему вдруг вам так кажется? Странно.

Comment: Нацкорпус дает статистику максимум. Так что проще - да не правильнее.